# what are the valid values for Timezone in icinga-web?

Tags: icinga

the documentation rightly points out that I can change the timezone in /etc/icinga/web/conf.d/translation.xml, but what are the valid values for timezone?

GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) is the default, EST (Eastern Standard Time) seems to work, but what I really want is EDT (Eastern Daylight Time), which is EST, but with daylight savings time awareness.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem sources from the underlaying agavi framework in combination with php not exposing the system timezone by default anymore (details: http://trac.agavi.org/ticket/1008)

etc/conf.d/translation.xml was added to Icinga Web for those people not being capable of modifying their php.ini - once you set the correct timezone (i.e 'Europe/Berlin') agavi and Icinga Web will be satisfied again. http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
Other than that, you may still play around with translation.xml and set values like 'GMT+6' or similar, but i would rather suggest fixing your php.ini anyways.